# DateTime values to create a separate class function

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have the following in all of my class functions:

```
var getDay = 3;

//DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
//DateTime now = new DateTime(2015, 11, 09);
//int dayOfWeek = (int)now.DayOfWeek;

DateTime startOfWeek6 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay);
DateTime endOfWeek6 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6);

DateTime startOfWeek5 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 7);
DateTime endOfWeek5 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 7);

DateTime startOfWeek4 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 14);
DateTime endOfWeek4 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 14);

DateTime startOfWeek3 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 21);
DateTime endOfWeek3 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 21);

DateTime startOfWeek2 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 28);
DateTime endOfWeek2 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 28);

DateTime startOfWeek1 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 35);
DateTime endOfWeek1 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 35);
```

Instead of pasting all those in every class function, is it possible to create 1 function class so I will just it there?

Comment: Yes. What do you want this method to return?

Comment: all date times, like startOfWeek6, endOfWeek6, startOfWeek5 etc

Comment: So stick them in a collection, like an array or list.

Comment: can you give a simple sample?

Comment: Okay. I am unsure what you want. Do you want to be able to call a method in several classes does the same across all classes? then use inheritance or a singleton. Do you want to some code that works across multiple weeks as Konstantin has already made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a class to hold the dates for a week:

```
public class Week
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a method that returns a collection of those, for example using `List<T>`:

```
public List<Week> GetWeeks()
{
    var weeks = new List<Week>();

    var week = new Week
    {
        Start = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay),
        End = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6),
    }

    weeks.Add(week);

    // add more weeks

    return weeks;

}
```

You may want to parameterize this method to allow it to create an arbitrary, non-fixed number of weeks.

Comment: The how will I call Star and End from another function? Is this correct?

var getWeeks = GetWeeks();
getWeeks.Start for start?

Comment: No, the method returns a collection, so you'll need to indicate which entry you want to access, for example `weeks[0].Start`.

Comment: is it possible to get it as Start, End etc?

Comment: Yes, `weeks[0].Start`, `weeks[0].End`, `weeks[1].Start`, `weeks[1].End` and so on. A method can have only one return variable (or multiple out parameters, but you really don't want that) and it's not really advisable to have many numbered variables. Learn to work with collections.

Comment: is this fine:

    var getWeeks = GetWeeks();
            var startOfWeek6 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek6;
            var endOfWeek6 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek6;
            var startOfWeek5 = getWeeks[0].startOfWeek5;
            var endOfWeek5 = getWeeks[0].endOfWeek5;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105794/discussion-between-bot-sundi-and-codecaster).

Comment: what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime GetStartOfWeek(DateTime now, int getDay, int n)
{
    return now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - n*7);
}

public DateTime GetEndOfWeek(DateTime now, int getDay, int n)
{
    return now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - n*7);
}
```

and after use like

```
public List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> GetStartsAndEndsOfWeeks(int numOfWeeks, int getDay, DateTime now)
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>>();
    for(int i = 0, i < numOfWeek, i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Tuple {
           Item1 =   GetStartOfWeek(now, getDay, i),
           Item2 =   GetEndOfWeek(now, getDay, i),
         });
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I would like to return all date times, like startOfWeek6, endOfWeek6, startOfWeek5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public abstract class WeekAcrossClasses
{
    public WeekAcrossClasses()
    {
    }

    protected List<DateTime> ReturnWeek(int getDay)
    {
        List<DateTime> returnList = new List<DateTime>();
        //DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        //DateTime now = new DateTime(2015, 11, 09);
        //int dayOfWeek = (int)now.DayOfWeek;

        DateTime startOfWeek6 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay);
        DateTime endOfWeek6 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6);

        DateTime startOfWeek5 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 7);
        DateTime endOfWeek5 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 7);

        DateTime startOfWeek4 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 14);
        DateTime endOfWeek4 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 14);

        DateTime startOfWeek3 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 21);
        DateTime endOfWeek3 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 21);

        DateTime startOfWeek2 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 28);
        DateTime endOfWeek2 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 28);

        DateTime startOfWeek1 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - 35);
        DateTime endOfWeek1 = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - 35);

        returnList.Add(startOfWeek6); //index 0
        returnList.Add(endOfWeek6); //index 1
        returnList.Add(startOfWeek5); //index 2
        returnList.Add(endOfWeek5); // ...
        returnList.Add(startOfWeek4);
        returnList.Add(endOfWeek4);
        returnList.Add(startOfWeek3);
        returnList.Add(endOfWeek3);
        returnList.Add(startOfWeek2);
        returnList.Add(endOfWeek2);
        returnList.Add(startOfWeek1);
        returnList.Add(endOfWeek1); //index 10

        return returnList;
    }

}
```

This code can then be used in other classes like so:

```
public class ArbClass : WeekAcrossClasses
{
    ArbClass()
    {
        List<DateTime> x = ReturnWeek(5);
    }
}
```

Should really consider trying to make the call smaller, since there is a lot of repeatable code that could be made smaller.

Answer (score -1):

```
 protected List<Week> getList(int count, int getDay)
{
    var list = new List<Week>();
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
    {
        Week w = new Week();
        w.Start = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay - n * 7);
        w.End = now.AddDays((-(int)now.DayOfWeek + 1) - getDay + 6 - n * 7);
        list.Add(w);
    }
    return list;
}


public class Week{    public DateTime Start { get; set; }    public DateTime nd { get; set; }}
```

Comment: Don't copy-paste together two existing answers without explanation.